# Url dentro de lista despegable no funciona en dispositivos moviles

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

estoy intentando realizar una lista desplegable con jQuery, pero no logro hacer que funcione en dispositivos móviles, ojalá me pudieran apoyar.

He colocado las URL dentro de los href, pero de esa manera el navegador no los abría en una pestaña nueva.

Los links funcionan bien en windows y mac, en dispositivos móviles el funcionamiento de despliegue funciona, lo único que no funciona es la última acción de abrir los links.

Estoy colocando todo el JavaScript que estoy utilizando en esa página

```js
$(document).ready(function(){jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("#jquery-accordion-menu").jqueryAccordionMenu(),jQuery(".colors a").click(function(){"default"!=$(this).attr("class")?($("#jquery-accordion-menu").removeClass(),$("#jquery-accordion-menu").addClass("jquery-accordion-menu").addClass($(this).attr("class"))):($("#jquery-accordion-menu").removeClass(),$("#jquery-accordion-menu").addClass("jquery-accordion-menu"))})})}),function(i,e,n,s){var t="jqueryAccordionMenu",u={speed:300,showDelay:0,hideDelay:0,singleOpen:!0,clickEffect:!0};function a(e,n){this.element=e,this.settings=i.extend({},u,n),this._defaults=u,this._name=t,this.init()}i.extend(a.prototype,{init:function(){this.openSubmenu(),this.submenuIndicators(),u.clickEffect&&this.addClickEffect()},openSubmenu:function(){i(this.element).children("ul").find("li").bind("click touchstart",function(n){if(n.stopPropagation(),n.preventDefault(),i(this).children(".submenu").length>0){if("none"==i(this).children(".submenu").css("display"))return i(this).children(".submenu").delay(u.showDelay).slideDown(u.speed),i(this).children(".submenu").siblings("a").addClass("submenu-indicator-minus"),u.singleOpen&&(i(this).siblings().children(".submenu").slideUp(u.speed),i(this).siblings().children(".submenu").siblings("a").removeClass("submenu-indicator-minus")),!1;i(this).children(".submenu").delay(u.hideDelay).slideUp(u.speed),i(this).children(".submenu").siblings("a").hasClass("submenu-indicator-minus")&&i(this).children(".submenu").siblings("a").removeClass("submenu-indicator-minus")}e.location.href=i(this).children("a").attr("href")})},submenuIndicators:function(){i(this.element).find(".submenu").length>0&&i(this.element).find(".submenu").siblings("a").append("<span class='submenu-indicator'>+</span>")},addClickEffect:function(){var e,n,s,t;i(this.element).find("a").bind("click touchstart",function(u){i(".ink").remove(),0===i(this).children(".ink").length&&i(this).prepend("<span class='ink'></span>"),(e=i(this).find(".ink")).removeClass("animate-ink"),e.height()||e.width()||(n=Math.max(i(this).outerWidth(),i(this).outerHeight()),e.css({height:n,width:n})),s=u.pageX-i(this).offset().left-e.width()/2,t=u.pageY-i(this).offset().top-e.height()/2,e.css({top:t+"px",left:s+"px"}).addClass("animate-ink")})}}),i.fn[t]=function(e){return this.each(function(){i.data(this,"plugin_"+t)||i.data(this,"plugin_"+t,new a(this,e))}),this}}(jQuery,window,document);
```

```css
.jquery-accordion-menu ul ul.submenu,.jquery-accordion-menu ul ul.submenu li ul.submenu{width:100%;display:none;position:static}.jquery-accordion-menu .submenu-indicator{position:absolute;line-height:19px;font-size:20px;-o-transition:transform .3s linear;-moz-transition:transform .3s linear;-webkit-transition:transform .3s linear;-ms-transition:transform .3s linear}.jquery-accordion-menu ul ul.submenu .submenu-indicator{line-height:16px}.jquery-accordion-menu .submenu-indicator-minus>.submenu-indicator{-ms-transform:rotate(45deg);-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);transform:rotate(45deg)}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" lang="ES-MX">
  <title>Menu </title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </meta>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div id="jquery-accordion-menu" class="jquery-accordion-menu green">
      <ul id="demo-list">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i>LISTA 1</a>
          <ul class="submenu tabla">
            <li>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='window.open("https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML", "_blank");return false;'><i class="fa fa-glass"></i>HTML</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-glass"></i>LISTA 2</a>
          <ul class="submenu tabla">
            <li>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='window.open("https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP", "_blank");return false;'><i class="fa fa-glass"></i>HTTP</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Realmente se necesita Javascript? ¿No es suficiente con enlaces normales y el atributo `target="_blank"`?

Comment: Si, en un inicio lo tenía declarado de la manera como comentas, pero no abría en una nueva pestaña

Comment: El problema está en el diseño o estructura del menú HTML. Te recomiendo que rediseñes pasó por pasó tu menú HTML y CSS

Comment: Un ejemplo: si pones la etiqueta `a` fuera del menú, está funciona muy bien